# How to detect alpha pixels in UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimage

I am trying to pass hitTest to the element underneath mine if the user touch is on an alpha pixel (transparent)

What I don't know is how to find out if pixel on CGPoint(20, 20) is full alpha or not?

iOS 4.+

Thanks, O.

Comment: [This link might be interesting for you][1]

there are more possible solutions to that

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the pixel RGBA and then get alpha

```
- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {
UIColor* color = nil;
CGImageRef inImage = self.image.CGImage;
// Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];
if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 

// Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
// allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
// raw image data in the specified color space.
CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, inImage); 

// Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
// context.
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
if (data != NULL) {
    //offset locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
    //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
    int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
    int alpha =  data[offset];
    int red = data[offset+1];
    int green = data[offset+2];
    int blue = data[offset+3];
    NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
}

// When finished, release the context
CGContextRelease(cgctx);
// Free image data memory for the context
if (data) { free(data); }

return color;
}

- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) inImage {

CGContextRef    context = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
void *          bitmapData;
int             bitmapByteCount;
int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

// Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);

// Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
// example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
// alpha.
bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

// Use the generic RGB color space.
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
if (colorSpace == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
    return NULL;
}

// Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
// where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
if (bitmapData == NULL)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    return NULL;
}

// Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
// per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
// (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
// specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,      // bits per component
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
if (context == NULL)
{
    free (bitmapData);
    fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
}

// Make sure and release colorspace before returning
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

return context;
}.
```

I've found this code in http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/

Comment: Looks good, thanks a lot, I will be testing the code today and will flag it if works, thanks again :) Ondrej